# deployJava.runApplet is not working

Tags: java, extjs, applet, jnlp, deployjava

Am using **applet** inside my "**Extjs UI framework**". If i called below "**applet.js**" file using "**index.html**", its working fine.

But, If i called inside any script, other than "**.html file**", then its not working. Just page data cleared and looks **full empty page**. Could you please advise me how to solve this issue.

I need to call my "applet.js" script though other ".js file", **not through ".html file"**. Is it possible? Kindly explain with examples.

**applet.js:-
----------**

```
var attributes = {
    tag: 'applet',
    code: 'com.src.test.Applet',
    archive: 'Test.jar',
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    id: 'test',
    mayscript: true
},
parameters = {
    jnlp_href: 'test.jnlp'
};

deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
```

**html:-
-----**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="applet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

**Sample code for Calling through other js file:-
-----------------------------------------------**    

    Ext.namespace('Test');

    launch: function () {
        this.test();
    },

    test: function () {
        var attributes = {
        tag: 'applet',
        code: 'com.src.test.Applet',
        archive: 'Test.jar',
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        id: 'test',
        mayscript: true
   },

   parameters = {
      jnlp_href: 'test.jnlp'
   };

   deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
   }
```

Thanks for looking into this....
Maria

Answer (score 0):

the applet tag is available in html only that why it need to execute on .html file

you should add that another .js script in html tag and checkout the if working or not

whenever you call

it replaces your .js script to associated tag and their attribute thats why might be it works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try. Is there any possibilities?